# Assign variable error if 'no rows selected' from query

Tags: plsql

I want to assign a variable from the sale of today by the menu item input. If the menu item has been sold yet, the variable should return 0. But it showed error instead:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT SUM(Selling_Price*Quantity_Sold)
            INTO V_Today_Sale
            FROM Bill_Item BI, Bill B
            WHERE BI.Bill_Number = B.Bill_Number AND
                  Menu_Item_Number = 1 AND 
                  Bill_Date = sysdate AND
                  (NVL(Paid_YN,'N') = 'Y' OR NVL(Posted_YN,'N') = 'Y')                  
            GROUP BY Menu_Item_Number
            ORDER BY Menu_Item_Number;
```

If I remove the variable assignment

```
SELECT SUM(Selling_Price*Quantity_Sold)            
            FROM Bill_Item BI, Bill B
            WHERE BI.Bill_Number = B.Bill_Number AND
                  Menu_Item_Number = 1 AND 
                  Bill_Date = sysdate AND
                  (NVL(Paid_YN,'N') = 'Y' OR NVL(Posted_YN,'N') = 'Y')                  
            GROUP BY Menu_Item_Number
            ORDER BY Menu_Item_Number;
```

the result will be:

```
no rows selected
```

It's correct since no sale has been made for today yet. But how can I make the query return 0 instead of no rows selected so that I can assign it to the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the query as shown to test without putting it in a block (using PL/SQL or Toad)?  If so, you need to define the variable and structure like this, with a call to NVL() around the SUM() call so V_Today_Sale gets a value if both inputs to SUM() are NULL, and add an exception to catch the NO_DATA_FOUND condition that sets V_Today_Sale to 0 if the where clause conditions are not met:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  V_Today_Sale number := 0;
BEGIN

SELECT NVL(SUM(Selling_Price*Quantity_Sold), 0)
            INTO V_Today_Sale
            FROM Bill_Item BI, Bill B
            WHERE BI.Bill_Number = B.Bill_Number AND
                  Menu_Item_Number = 1 AND 
                  Bill_Date = sysdate AND
                  (NVL(Paid_YN,'N') = 'Y' OR NVL(Posted_YN,'N') = 'Y')                  
            GROUP BY Menu_Item_Number
            ORDER BY Menu_Item_Number;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      V_Today_Sale :=0;

END;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_Today_Sale);
```

Comment: I copied that select statement from my function, so yea I did declare it. 
I also did try NVL() around the SUM, but it didn't work. I ran your code, and it showed the error "no data found."

Comment: @Renna You'll need to add an Exception that catches NO_DATA_FOUND and if caught, sets V_Today_Sale to 0. I'll update my example.